# How can i connect my stripe terminal by internet

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

Please tell me how can I connect a terminal to the android application via the Internet.
Now I have a terminal BBPOS WisePOS E, I wrote an application some time ago and now I want to add functionality for connecting without bluetooth.

I've tried changing the method to internet, but it hasn't worked so far. Should this be enough, or do I need to write additional processing for connecting via the Internet?

```
DiscoveryConfiguration(0, DiscoveryMethod.INTERNET, false)
```

Comment: Could you please share more details about your integration? Are you having a particular error?

In the meanwhile, I suggest you to take a look at this guide:
https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/connect-reader?terminal-sdk-platform=android&reader-type=internet

However, for BBPOS WisePOS E, Stripe recommends the server-driven integration[1], which uses the Stripe API instead of a Terminal SDK to collect payments.
[1] https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/connect-reader?terminal-sdk-platform=server-driven&reader-type=internet

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however I already found the answer to my question in the stripe documentation

Answer (score 0):

First, you need connect a terminal to internet, [try this](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/setup-reader/bbpos-wisepos-e#connecting-to-the-internet).

[Here](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/connect-reader?terminal-sdk-platform=android&reader-type=internet) how to connect this terminal to your android app. You should register your terminal by API or on Stripe dashboard

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I re-read the documentation in more detail before your answer and found the solution for myself in these links!